# Error in CIL. Method not found: '?'

Tags: exception, compiler-construction, cil

I'm writing my own compiler for the fun of it xD. It's compiling to CIL using Mono.Cecil, and when I decompile it or look at the CIL it looks ok, however, when I run it I get a crash (exception) stating that "Method was not found: '?'".

Looking at the method the crash is generated in (stacktrace shows which method) this is the CIL for the given method:

```
.method public hidebysig virtual 
    instance class [Totem.Library]Totem.Library.TotemValue Execute () cil managed 
{
    IL_0000: callvirt class [Totem.Library]Totem.Library.TotemUndefined [Totem.Library]Totem.Library.TotemUndefined::get_Value()
    IL_0005: ret
}
```

Totem.Library is a external dll written in C# (not compiled with my compiler, and should thus work). The property being accessed (TotemUndefined.Value, static property) has no means of causing an exception (it just returns a singleton created in the static constructor of TotemUndefined).

And I was wondering, is there anything wrong with this CIL? Or is more information required to find the issue (can upload full source, only a couple hundred lines in total as of now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `callvirt` to call a static function. That won't work, simply use `call`.